# Route chaining is not working in Express V4

Tags: express, controller, routes

I am using express v4.15.2 and npm version is 3.10.10.
In this I am trying to use route chaining below is my code:

**route/route.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();
var app=express();

var user=require('../controller/controller');
module.exports=function(app){
app.route('/api/user').get(user.login);
};
```

**controller/controller.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var app =express();

exports.login=function(req,res,next){

res.json({"msg":"Hello"});

};
```

**server.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var app =express();
var router=require('./module/route/route');

app.use('/',router);



app.listen(3000,function(req,res){
console.log('Server Started');
});
```

Above given are my route and controller code. I am trying to create a route chain to use methods `get`, `post`, `put`, `delete` on a single API i.e `/api/user` .

But its not working, my api is not getting hit and even log is not showing any error.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use it like this: `app.route('/api/user').get(user.login).post(user.update).delete(user.remove);` etc.?

Comment: Yes I want same

Answer (score 0):

You would want to export app, and not an anonymous function in route.js.

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();
var app=express();

var user=require('../controller/controller');

app.route('/api/user').get(user.login);

module.exports = app;
```

Also, consider if you really need all the functions in app in your route. Maybe you should use the Router object instead. In that case you just change to:

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();

var user=require('../controller/controller');

router.route('/api/user').get(user.login);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the same but its also not working for me.

Comment: are you sure you have the correct path to route? router=require('./module/route/route');? Based on your description it should be ('./route/route').

Comment: My problem has been solved. I have to make changes on `server.js`. I replaced `app.use('/',router);` to `router(app)` and now its working great.